# sort in xslt when before creating table of data

Tags: sorting, xslt, xls

I am trying to take the data and put in a table and sort it before I output to the table and when I do it sorts the first columun and rest of the column are not sorted at all.  I am trying to sort by streetNuame and only works on the first table column

```
<fo:table>
  <fo:table-column width="82mm"/>
  <fo:table-column width="82mm"/>
  <fo:table-column width="82mm"/>
  <fo:table-body>
    <xsl:for-each select="route/address[position() mod 3 = 1]">
      <xsl:sort select="streetName"/>
      <fo:table-row>
        <xsl:apply-templates select=". | following-sibling::*[3 > position()]"/>

        <xsl:variable name="vPos" select="position()"/>
        <xsl:variable name="vUnfilled"
        select=" 2 - count(following-sibling::*)"/>
        <xsl:if test="position() = last()">
          <xsl:for-each select="../*[not(position() > $vUnfilled)]">
            <fo:table-cell>
              <fo:block>
                <xsl:value-of select="' '"/>
              </fo:block>
            </fo:table-cell>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:if>
      </fo:table-row>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </fo:table-body>
</fo:table>
```

XML below:

```
    <route>
       <name>blah</name>

       <address>
          <fullStreet>blah</fullStreet>
          <streetNumber>blah</streetNumber>
          <streetName>blah</streetName>

       </address>
```

Comment: what does the XML looks like?

Comment: just updated with xml code

Comment: Do you have a template that matches `address`?  If so, could you show us that?

Comment: Are you using XSLT1.0 or XSLT2.0?

Comment: xslt1.0 and yes I have template and will load as soon as I can.